# Line to the Y axis on hover

Tags: highcharts

charts/stack-overflow,

I would like to make it easy for end users to compare points in an area/line chart. As such, when they hover on a point, I would like to draw a horizontal line from that point all the way to the left and to right. Unlike a plotLine (which i understand to be static), this would be appear/disappear/change based on which point you are hovering on.

You can see something similar on the stockcharts where a vertical line goes down to the X-axis.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `yAxis.crosshair`:

```
    yAxis: {
        crosshair: {
            ...
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/5003/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.crosshair