# Rings around axis on hover on highcharts Variable radius pie

Tags: highcharts

Hello Highcharts and stackoverflow,

I would like to make it easy for end users to compare wedgets in a Variable radius pie chart (basically the same as [Line to the Y axis on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702783/line-to-the-y-axis-on-hover) but radial). As such, when they hover on a wedge, I would like to draw a "ring" around the circle for easy comparisons.  This would be appear/disappear/change based on which point you are hovering on.

(in some ways - like a mix between the visualization of the Variable radius pie chart with the concept of an axis like a Polar/Radar Chart)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use column series in polar chart with crosshair:

```
    chart: {
        polar: true
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0,
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [...]
    }],
    yAxis: {
        crosshair: {
            color: 'red',
            zIndex: 3
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/5005/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.polar

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.crosshair

Comment: but each wedge is still the same size/central-angle in a polar chart... in the Variable radius pie chart, the size/central-angle of each wedge is different.

Comment: Hi @JMH, Sorry, I missed that. Please check a solution for variablepie: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m8xzdfkr/1/